# How can i remove system menu items in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to remove system menus; for example, in the Message app I want to remove the **Send** option from the menu.

There is a way to add menus using

```
   ApplicationMenuItemRepository.getInstance()
    .addMenuItem(ApplicationMenuItemRepository.MENUITEM_SYSTEM, this);
```

and also to `removeMenuItem()` in the same way, but I'm not able to remove menu items.

How can I use this, or any alternate way, to remove menu?

Comment: Please explain what exactly you want to achieve. `removeMenuItem()` will only remove your application menu item not the menu items in some other application's menu items. If it is your own app, then you can override `makeMenu()` method.

Comment: as far as I know there's no way in RIM API java sdk to remove system menu items. Only adding/removing new custom items is possible, but you cannot remove already existing system menu items.

Comment: i want to remove cut copy paste option from every menu of device...